# Unable to change dragging cursor style when dragging an object in Chrome using JavaScript and CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to change the default dragging cursor style when dragging an object in Chrome using JavaScript and CSS. I have added the `draggable` attribute to the element and attached event listeners for `dragstart` and `dragend` events. In the `dragstart` event listener, I add a class called `dragging` to the element, which should change the cursor style to a pointer. However, the cursor style does not change as expected when I drag the element.

What I tried :

```
listElement.setAttribute("draggable", "true");

listElement.addEventListener("dragstart", () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        listElement.classList.add("dragging");
    }, 0);
});

listElement.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
    listElement.classList.remove("dragging");
});
```

```
.list-name.dragging {
    opacity: 0 !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

Comment: Try: `*[draggable=true] { cursor: pointer; }`

Comment: Please post a [repro]

Comment: @LightningMcQueen that will add the style always not only during the drag event

Comment: @tacoshy 

it is in a minimal reproducible version, he is a code pen example : https://codepen.io/mahdy02/pen/vYQJYbB

as you can see when you drag the text it is getting colored in blue, but the cursor is still the default.

Answer (score 0):

If you cancel the event you can see your cursor css changes. This probably means you would need to implement the dragging logic yourself.

```js
const listElement = document.getElementById("listElement");

listElement.setAttribute("draggable", "true");

listElement.addEventListener("dragstart", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  listElement.classList.add("dragging");
});

listElement.addEventListener("dragend", (event) => {
  listElement.classList.remove("dragging");
});
```

```css
.list-name.dragging:active {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mother_class {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mother_class">
  <div id="listElement" class="list-name" draggable>Draggable Element</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Preventing the default effect would make me lose the default dragging effects which makes it necessary to implement the dragging effect myself. Can you think of a way to keep the default dragging effect and only style the cursor ?

Comment: what is the desired drag effect? maybe implementing it's not so bad

Comment: I have a sortable list to be sorted by drag and drop effect. I would prefer not not put each list item in a div and apply the drag drop effect on the div which pretty much resolve my problem. Instead I would like to sort it directly by dragging and dropping the list item.